# how to make top offset with vertically tiled background image

Tags: css

I set a background image(1000x10px) to my `body` page and vertically tiled it to achieve two column effect:

```
background: url(pozadina.png) repeat-y 50%;
```

Now I wish to move it some pixels towards bottom to have that nice `margin-top` effect, but can't figure it out with `background-position`, and don't even know if possible.

Any help appreciated. Thanks you! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
body:before{
        content: "";
        height: 15px;
        display: block;
        background: white;
    }
```

Thanks you guy! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
background-position: center, 90%;
```

or

```
background-position: center, bottom;
```

Comment: It has to be centered. And anyways it doesn't not make it start 10% off the top. Check it out, try! ;)

Comment: Try to do it. Make a 1000x10px image and apply it to body. It is not working. But... solution from above makes it yummy. ;)